# How are Consumers implemented in NATS

Tags: go, nats.io, nats-jetstream

The definition of a consumer in NATS is

> A consumer is a stateful view of a stream. It acts as interface for
> clients to consume a subset of messages stored in a stream and will
> keep track of which messages were delivered and acknowledged by
> clients.

**I'm more interested in understanding what exactly is a consumer under the hood ? Is it a process, a thread, some kind of socket i.e. a network entity etc ?**

I'm designing a system where I'm using NATS 2.9, so a consumer can't have more than one subject filter. I want to create 1 consumer per subject filter and I'm concerned about the performance & resource implications of creating about 10,000 consumers in the worst case.

**Is a consumer an expensive resource to create in NATS ?**

Creating a single consumer with a very generic subject filter is an alternative I'm considering but it doesn't fit into my design neatly as several go routines will be sharing this one global consumer as opposed to creating one consumer per go routine, each go routine will consume and process its own subject filter's messages thus ensuring a sort of logical isolation as far as my design goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are **extremely** cheap. Basically, a connection to NATS is a multiplexer:

- It connects to a nats server
- The it expresses its interest in topics via one or more subscriptions.
- The connection then receives new messages and sends them to the appropriate consumer you set up.

I created a test setup where I was able to *easily* have 1500 consumers on a single machine (my laptop), including a NATS cluster and a producer with the whole setup still being able to send and receive several million `"Hello, World!"`s per *second*. I actually needed to scale up the producers considerably to even manage to get any meaningful data.

### The environment

#### Dockerfile

We create a Docker image from the binaries you will find below.
It is pretty much standard.

```
FROM golang:1.22-alpine3.19 as builder
ARG BINARY_NAME="producer"
WORKDIR /tmp/cmds
COPY . .
RUN go build -o ${BINARY_NAME} ./cmds/${BINARY_NAME}

FROM alpine:3.19
ARG BINARY_NAME="producer"
ENV BINARY_NAME=${BINARY_NAME}
COPY --from=builder /tmp/cmds/${BINARY_NAME} /usr/local/bin/${BINARY_NAME}
```

#### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  # A nats cluster with 3 nodes
  nats:
    image: nats:2.1.9
    command:
      - "--debug"
      - "--cluster"
      - "nats://0.0.0.0:6222"
      - "--routes"
      # Note that this needs to be prefixed with the
      # name of the directory that the docker-compose file is in.
      # In my case it's "nats-consumers-78214263" (a mnemonic and question ID)
      - "nats://nats-consumers-78214263-nats-1:6222"
    hostname: nats
    deploy:
      replicas: 3

  # The producer
  # You can scale this up via `docker compose scale producer=n`
  # to see how the consumers handle the load
  producer:
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - BINARY_NAME=producer
    command: ["/usr/local/bin/producer"]
    environment:
      - PRODUCER_NATS_URL=nats://nats:4222
      - PRODUCER_PRODUCERS=1
  
  # The consumer
  # You can scale this up via `docker compose scale consumer=n`
  # to see how the consumers handle the load
  consumer:
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - BINARY_NAME=consumer
    command: ["/usr/local/bin/consumer"]
    environment:
      - CONSUMER_NATS_URL=nats://nats:4222
      - CONSUMER_TOPIC=test.>
      - CONSUMER_CONSUMERS=15000
```

### The Services

#### Producer

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net/url"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "sync/atomic"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    "github.com/alecthomas/kong"
    "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
)

var producercfg struct {
    NatsURL   url.URL `kong:"name='nats-url',help='NATS server URL',default='nats://nats:4222'"`
    Producers int     `kong:"name='producers',help='Number of producers to start',default='1'"`
}

func main() {
    ctx := kong.Parse(&producercfg, kong.DefaultEnvars("PRODUCER"))

    // Run the configured number of producers in goroutines
    // Note that all producers share the same NATS connection
    // Each producer sends a messsage every 100ms

    nc, err := nats.Connect(producercfg.NatsURL.String())
    ctx.FatalIfErrorf(err, "Could not connect to NATS server: %s", producercfg.NatsURL.String())
    defer nc.Close()

    // Handle SIGINT and SIGTERM to shut down gracefully
    // We use a context here because that makes it easy for us to shut down
    // all goroutines in one fell swoop, but gracefully so.
    sigs, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    defer cancel()

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var sent atomic.Int64

    for i := 0; i < producercfg.Producers; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(producerContext context.Context, conn *nats.Conn, id int) {
            ctx.Printf("Starting publisher to %s", fmt.Sprintf("test.%d", id))
            defer wg.Done()

            for {
                // We have...
                select {
                // either received a signal to shut down...
                case <-producerContext.Done():
                    ctx.Printf("Producer %d shutting down", id)
                    // ... so we return from the goroutine.
                    return
                default:
                    // or we send a message.
                    sent.Add(1)
                    err := conn.Publish(fmt.Sprintf("test.%d", id), []byte("Hello, World!"))
                    ctx.FatalIfErrorf(err, "Could not publish message: %s", err)
                }
            }
        }(sigs, nc, i)
    }

    tick := time.NewTicker(time.Second)

evt:
    for {
        // Either we receive a signal to shut down...
        select {
        case <-sigs.Done():
            cancel()
            break evt
        // ... or we print out the number of messages sent so far.
        case <-tick.C:
            ctx.Printf("Sent %d messages", sent.Load())
        }
    }
    ctx.Printf("Received signal, shutting down producers...")
    wg.Wait()
    ctx.Printf("All producers shut down. Exiting.")
}
```

Note that you might need to scale up the producer in order to get meaningful data.

#### Consumer

Also, pretty much standard:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "net/url"
    "os/signal"
    "sync/atomic"
    "syscall"
    "time"

    "github.com/alecthomas/kong"
    "github.com/nats-io/nats.go"
)

var consumercfg struct {
    NatsURL   url.URL `kong:"name='nats-url',help='NATS server URL',default='nats://nats:4222'"`

    // Note that with this topic, ALL consumers we create here
    // will receive ALL messages by ALL producers. 
    Topic     string  `kong:"name='topic',help='NATS topic to subscribe to',default='test.>'"`
    Consumers int     `kong:"name='consumers',help='Number of consumers to start',default='1'"`
}

func main() {
    ctx := kong.Parse(&consumercfg, kong.DefaultEnvars("CONSUMER"))
    ctx.Printf("Starting consumer on %s, subscribing to %s", consumercfg.NatsURL.String(), consumercfg.Topic)

    nc, err := nats.Connect(consumercfg.NatsURL.String())
    ctx.FatalIfErrorf(err, "Could not connect to NATS server: %s", consumercfg.NatsURL.String())
    // Run the configured number of consumers in goroutines
    // Note that all consumers share the same NATS connection
    // Each consumer subscribes to the configured topic
    // and counts the number of messages received, printing them out every second.
    // The consumers will stop when SIGINT or SIGTERM are received.

    sigs, cancel := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    defer cancel()

    for i := 0; i < consumercfg.Consumers; i++ {
        go func(sigs context.Context, conn *nats.Conn, topic string, id int) {

            count := atomic.Int64{}

            // We use the same connection!
            sub, err := conn.Subscribe(topic, func(msg *nats.Msg) {
                // Callback for processing a new message.
                count.Add(1)
            })
            ctx.FatalIfErrorf(err, "Could not subscribe to topic %s: %s", topic, err)
            defer sub.Unsubscribe()

            tick := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
            for {
                select {
                case <-sigs.Done():
                    ctx.Printf("Received shutdown signal.")
                    ctx.Printf("Final result: received %d messages", count.Load())
                    return
                case <-tick.C:
                    ctx.Printf("%6d Received %d messages", id, count.Load())
                }
            }
        }(sigs, nc, consumercfg.Topic, i)
    }

    <-sigs.Done()
}
```

If interested, I can publish the code and stuff on GitHub.